# Laravel pivot from pivot tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, db-schema

I have this database schema:

[image]

is there anyway I can get to the `school_class_arms` table from School using a pivot or something? Or would I have to `add school_id` to `the school_class_arms` table?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an `Eloquent Model` for `school_class_arms` table ? Post relevant code.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha No ofense, I know you are trying to help me, but I dont see what can be more relevant than the schema itself. Everything is pretty much straight forward, `School hasMany() Classes`, `School hasMany() Arms`, and `School should haveMany() ClassesArm`. I know if I will add `school_id` to the `school_class_arms` table I will have it simpler. I was wondering if Laravel has the power to go thru pivot tables to a pivot from pivot tables. Thank you for checking into the question.

Comment: What result you need using that far pivot table?

Comment: @deczo I need the id of the relationship which will get me the class name per arms.

Comment: Actually I need that id to use it in another pivot with school subjects. I am thinking that will go with adding `school_id` to the `school_class_arms` table.

Comment: You would need additional models for pivot tables, so it might be better to make that far pivot table link 3 models instead. Knowing only this part of the design it's hard to suggest anything.

Comment: @deczo I agree with you, and this is what I am going to do.

Comment: You aren't using pivot tables, you're using direct relationships via `hasMany`. Pivot tables do not have row identifiers. Look into using `hasManyThrough()`.